# Need Help Understanding For loops with Variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am going through the book Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, and need help understanding what's really happening with the code.

```
catNames = []

while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) + 1) + ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]
print('The cat names are:')
for name in catNames:
    print('  ' + name)
```

now it makes sense until

```
for name in catNames:
        print('  ' + name)
```

I am only used to seeing for loops with range(), and this does not make sense to me. A detailed explanation would be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer; this tells others that the issue is resolved and helps people find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain it to you on a simple example:

```
# You create some list of elements
list = [1, 2, 3, 9, 4]
  
# Using for loop you print out all the elements
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

It will print to the console:

```
1
2
3
9
4
```

And you can also do it by using `range` but you have to know the length of the array:

```
# You create some list of elements
list = [1, 2, 3, 9, 4]
  
# get the list length
length = len(list)
  
# Iterating the index
# same as 'for i in range(len(list))'
for i in range(length):
    print(list[i])
```

Console output will look the same as before